# Python midi module - cant build into exe

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I am tring to build standalone exe from an python script.
Script itself works fine. Build was done with pyinstaller and python version 3.7. It seems that it can not load a part of midi module.

[Error after starting the exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO73Z.png)

imports used in the script:

```
import mido
import rtmidi
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Python 3.6.
It was resolved by adding

```
import mido.backends.rtmidi
```

For your case, probably replace from following line.

```
import rtmidi
```

Ref. (portmidi case)
https://github.com/mido/mido/issues/17